# Как сделать блок точно по размеру текста?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать такое меню, чтобы две строки текста были ровно по размеру блока и без отбивки, не используя отрицательный margin?

```css
div {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: coral;
}

div p {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 0.64;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>TO ORDER <br> ЗАКАЗАТЬ
  </p>
</div>
```

Если подобрать line-height то текст начинает выходить за размеры блока. Сам блочный элемент p становиться меньше, чем его содержимое, с уменьшением межстрочного интервала. Почему это происходит?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, это сейчас невозможно. Могу предложить только подобрать значение в `em` под конкретный шрифт.

```css
p {
  font-family: "Arial";
  background: coral;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: .75em;
  color: silver;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

p::first-line {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<p>To order<br>Заказать</p>
```

Comment: мб через getBoundingClientRect?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, он учитывает line-height, насколько я помню.

Comment: А если просто сделать в svg? К нему можно применить alt-text?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, за тобой пришли ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy ничего не знаю, у меня сегодня новая залипуха - https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/BayBzVj

Comment: @Stranger in the Q я обиделся :(( почему я только сейчас узнаю о залипухах ... и где старые залипухи ?

Comment: @Leks вот тут моя залипушная https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pens/public

Comment: @Stranger in the Q спасибо а почему здесь не хотите публиковать формате вопрос - ответ ?

Comment: @Leks бог его знает, мне не нравится писать тексты, не мое это.

Comment: @Stranger in the Q понятно, удачи

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: coral;
}

div p {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 0.9em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>TO ORDER <br> ЗАКАЗАТЬ
  </p>
</div>
```